# getElementByID works, getElementsByClassName does not work

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a solution where the javascript changes div1 instead of div2.
This code works with `getElementbyId` but does not work with `getElementbyClassName`. Why does this not work?

```
function refer(Div1, Div2) {
    if (document.getElementByClassName('Div1')) {
        if (document.getElementByClassName('Div1').style.display == 'block') {
            var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('Div2');
            for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) { 
                elems[i].style.display = 'block';
            }

            var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('Div1');
            for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
                elem[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first 2 methods are misspelt. `document.getElement`s`ByClassName` they need an `s`

Comment: There is no getElementByClassName method and when you add the "s" you can not just reference the collection to get the one element.

Comment: document.getElementByClassName('Div1').style.display == 'block' ¿If exist any element with class Div1?

Comment: @AlvaroJoao—w3schools is not an authority on anything, please don't reference it. Far better to reference actual standards or specifications, e.g. [*WHATWG*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname) or [*W3C*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyname). And there is no *getElementByClassName*, check the spelling. ;-)

Comment: There is a question with almost the exact the same title as yours. Didn't you find that one?

Comment: @RobG Thanks for the tips and the reference! I will follow them starting today!

Comment: @AlvaroJoao I am glad Google fixed the spelling mistake so you got the correct method.

Comment: @epascarello yep ! my bad! :) no hard felling

Comment: I am posting a fiddle of mine for the reference. [https://jsfiddle.net/60g80qad/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to use `getElementsByClassName`: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/m27hg8ba/)

Is this working for you?

```
array = document.getElementsByClassName('div1');
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

In Chrome and Edge works with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a array as an object, the difference between `getElementbyId` and 
`getElementsByClassName` is that:

- `getElementbyId` will return you an object.
- `getElementsByClassName` will return you an array.

### getElementsByClassName

> The `getElementsByClassName(classNames)` method takes a string that
>   contains an unordered set of unique space-separated tokens
>   representing classes. When called, the method must return a live
>   `NodeList` object containing all the elements in the document that
>   have all the classes specified in that argument, having obtained the
>   classes by splitting a string on spaces. If there are no tokens
>   specified in the argument, then the method must return an empty
>   NodeList.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyclassname

### getElementById

> The getElementById() method accesses the first element with the specified id.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp

in your code the lines:

> 1 `if (document.getElementByClassName('Div1')) {`
>
> 2 `if (document.getElementByClassName('Div1').style.display == 'block') {`

will **NOT** work as expected: specially the second(2) line,
 cos the `getElementByClassName` will return an array, and the array will **NOT** have the `style` property, you gonna access each `element` by iterating them.

That's why the function `getElementById` was working for you, this function will return you the direct object , and so you will be able to access the `style` property.

One working code:

```
function refer(Div1,Div2) {

           var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('Div1');
            var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('Div2');
            for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {

                if (elem[i]) {
                   if (elem[i].style.display == 'block') {

                       elem[i].style.display = 'none';

                       for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) { 
                           elems[i].style.display = 'block';
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
}
```